# What's the best practice for activating/deactivating UI components in Unity3D?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I'm making a UI for my Unity3D game and am activating/deactivating UI components in  order to display or hide them, which works but is slow. The first time a UI component is activated, it is particularly slower than thereafter. Is there a best practice as to how UI should be hidden/displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [disabling canvas renderer](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/other-ui-optimization-techniques-and-tips#disabling-canvas-renderers). It should be a lot less stressing on the CPU than using `GameObject.SetActive()` if you have nested panels and what not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sprite Mask. Although the areas of use of the Sprite Mask are wide, it is generally used to hide unwanted parts of an image.